# PHP - Problems in logging in to Facebook chat using JAXL

Tags: php, facebook, xmpp

I try to use the new JAXL 3.0 to connect to Facebook's chat.
They have an example called "echo_facebook_client.php" in their examples:

```
<?php
/**
 * Jaxl (Jabber XMPP Library)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009-2012, Abhinav Singh <me@abhinavsingh.com>.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 * the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 * distribution.
 *
 * * Neither the name of Abhinav Singh nor the names of his
 * contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 * from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRIC
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
 * ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 */

if($argc != 4) {
    echo "Usage: $argv[0] fb_user_id_or_username fb_app_key fb_access_token\n";
    exit;
}

//
// initialize JAXL object with initial config
//
require_once 'jaxl.php';
$client = new JAXL(array(
    // (required) credentials
    'jid' => $argv[1].'@chat.facebook.com',
    'fb_app_key' => $argv[2],
    'fb_access_token' => $argv[3],

    // (required) force facebook oauth
    'auth_type' => 'X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM',

    // (optional)
    //'resource' => 'resource'
));

//
// add necessary event callbacks here
//

$client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
    global $client;
    _debug("got on_auth_success cb, jid ".$client->full_jid->to_string());
    $client->set_status("available!", "dnd", 10);
});

$client->add_cb('on_auth_failure', function($reason) {
    global $client;
    $client->send_end_stream();
    _debug("got on_auth_failure cb with reason $reason");
});

$client->add_cb('on_chat_message', function($stanza) {
    global $client;

    // echo back incoming message stanza
    $stanza->to = $stanza->from;
    $stanza->from = $client->full_jid->to_string();
    $client->send($stanza);
});

$client->add_cb('on_disconnect', function() {
    _debug("got on_disconnect cb");
});

//
// finally start configured xmpp stream
//
$client->start();
echo "done\n";

?>
```

I changed the jid value to the userid of the facebook Account I try to chat with, fb_app_key to the app id of my app and fb_access_token to an access token I got while requesting the xmpp_login privilege.

However when I run the script it keeps telling me "got on_auth_failure cb with reason not-authorized"

But what is not authorized and why not autorized, I have the xmpp permission.

Then I tried the example code of facebook on their document page for the chat api which you can find here developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/.

I gave it the same credentials and it was able to login at first try so the error has to be somewhere at the jaxl side.

I have no clue about the XMPP protocol so it would be really handy to use JAXL instead of coding the functions I need on my own like it is done on the facebook example.

Does anybody have suggestions why the JAXL code does not run?
The last update was 8 days ago so theoretically it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to pass `'force_tls' => true` as JAXL constructor config option.
As per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/#jabber tls negotiation has been made
mandatory for x-facebook-platform authentication.

A relevant thread from jaxl groups/forums https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US&fromgroups#!topic/jaxl/Z7z32lMqG44 which discuss this very use case.